# Can I minify the Google font?

Tags: html, css, minify, google-fonts

Is there a way to get the google-font compressed from the server?
When I get the CSS for the fonts from Google's server it looks like this:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/ek4gzZ-GeXAPcSbHtCeQI_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/mErvLBYg_cXG3rLvUsKT_fesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
 .
 .
 .
 etc
}
```

The styles aren't compressed (delete the comments and remove white spaces) therefore I get less reputation on PageSpeed Insights which means less SEO and I also get less perform in my web-page.
I don't want to use @import since it's not recommended.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the total download size (i.e. the size of the font resource) to a minimum, or just the CSS?

Comment: just the css...

Answer (score 1):

According to this online post here (https://discourse.roots.io/t/best-way-to-use-google-fonts/455/2) you cannot load the fonts minified directly from the good servers. However, you could minify the code yourself, either manually or a website such as https://cssminifier.com/.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It seems a good solution but I'm currently working with static pages.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) and my experience you can have optimization only trough specifying script subsets or using the Web Font Loader.